our performance might come off as grudging or cynical

Over millions of years, those pressures selected for people who are
sensitive to and skilled at maximizing their standing. It’s what the
anthropologist Brian Hare called “survival of the friendliest.”  The
result was the development of a sociometer: a tendency to
unconsciously monitor how other people in our community seem to
perceive us. We process that information in the form of self-esteem
and such related emotions as pride, shame, or insecurity. These
emotions compel us to do more of what makes our community value us and
less of what doesn’t. And, crucially, they are meant to make that
motivation feel like it is coming from within. If we realized, on a
conscious level, that we were responding to social pressure, our
performance might come off as grudging or cynical, making it less
persuasive. (from The Chaos Machine: The Inside Story of How Social
Media Rewired Our Minds and Our World by Max Fisher)

I have difficulty understanding the bold part. Every part of this sentence is confusing to me.
First, the meanings of 'come off', 'grudging', and 'cynical' were difficult for me to grasp. My guess is as follows:
'come off' means 'to give a particular impression' that is, 'To be interpreted in a particular way' as in 'I hope I didn't come off as rude or aloof';
'grudging' means 'reluctant';
'cynical' means 'Selfishly or callously calculating'.
So, if I paraphrase the sentence, it would be 'Our performance would be perceived as reluctant or calculating (by ourselves, not by others)
Is this correct?
Second, my paraphrase is where my second question arises. In my paraphrase, I said '(by ourselves, not by others)', which is to say, 'we perceive our performance as reluctant or calculating.'
Is this correct? Who perceives our performance as reluctant or calculating? Is 'We' correct?
Third, in 'making it less persuasive', which is the 'it'?
I guess it could be 'social pressure' in 'we were responding to social pressure', or 'that motivation' in 'to make that motivation feel like it is coming from within.' Which is correct?
Fourth, which makes 'it' less persuasive?

(the fact that) our performance might come off as grudging or cynical
our performance

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Why on earth would you think [be perceived] by ourselves, not by others? That makes no sense at all. Obviously if you give a particular impression, that imprression is perceived by other people.

What is the difference between come across as and come off as? Answer: None, but across is far more common.

@FumbleFingers Why on earth would I think [be perceived by ourselves]? Because I am an English language learner. Because I don't know the exact nuances of expressions like 'come off as.' Isn't this site for language learners? Because I don't know the nuance and exact meaning of the sentence, I am here to get help. As a language learner, I cannot help thinking to some extent based on translations. I think a human can perceive his own behavior in a particular way, as well as other people's behaviors. (I am talking about 'perception', not concerning the specific expression 'come off as')

Don't you sometimes get to realize you see your behavior in a particular way as if you became a third-person? Anyway, now I understand that in the sentence, 'come off as' should be interpreted as 'be perceived by others' thanks to an answer, which someone kind gave a few hours ago but now has been deleted. (I don't know why they deleted it, it was really helpful to me)

My guess: 'come off' means 'to give a particular impression' that is, 'To be interpreted in a particular way' as in 'I hope I didn't come off as rude or aloof'; 'grudging' means 'reluctant'; 'cynical' means 'Selfishly or callously calculating'. YES, CORRECT.
Second, we perceive our performance as reluctant or calculating.' Is 'We' correct? NO, it comes off as (whatever) to ITS AUDIENCE.
Third, in 'making it less persuasive', which is the 'it'? IT is the performance.
Fourth, which makes 'it' less persuasive? Our performance coming off as grudging or cynical.

I appreciate your detailed answer according to my points of the question:)

To put it in other words:
If we realized that our motivations were not originating within ourselves but were being supplied to us, there would be no way to hide our loss of innocence. Our demeanor would reveal that we were grudging or cynical puppets if we tried to act like our old naive, jolly selves.
